# Are there mathematical blogs/websites which publish "pop-math"?

Tags: soft-question, recreational-mathematics

Are there mathematical blogs/websites which publish "pop-math" (that is, simple and nice articles on interesting topics aimed at students/non-specialists/specialists-who-want-to-have-some-fun-and-distract-from-their-"problems"-for-a-few-minutes)?

(Obviously, I mean, known ones, which accept submissions)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It might not be exactly the kind of website you're looking for but since noone has answered it yet I'll give it a try:

[[LinkedIn] Math, Math Education, Math Culture](http://www.linkedin.com/groups/Math-Math-Education-Math-Culture-33207/about)

As a member of that group I can say that there does tend to appear some interesting stuff from time to time and if you contribute with your own math topic, article or discussion, your erroft will be also appreciated.